# cURL live command output executed by popen() and fread() in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am building an internal tool suite for part of our technical team that involves running commands against an array of remote servers around the world. I've come up against a minor problem, but I cant think of a way around it easily. Below is the process for this specific segment of the tool set:

- Web form on master server, user inputs type of check, and hostname/IP
- Submit input variables to PHP script on master server that builds the URL to cURL, cURL's it against the remote server (lets just limit to one remote server for this example), and echo's its output.
- Remote server recieves web request to PHP script with variables, runs a linux shell command to suit the request, and returns its output back via cURL to the master

So that's all fine, but I decided to get fancy with the traceroute and ping tools, and had them live output the progress to browser through the use of popen() and fread(), example below:

```
#Get the variables
$type = $_GET['type'];
$hostname = $_GET['host'];

#Start switch to decide what to do
switch ($type) {
  case "trace":
      $cmd = "traceroute $hostname";
      while (@ ob_end_flush());
      $proc = popen($cmd, 'r');
      echo "<pre>";
      while (!feof($proc))
        {
          echo fread($proc, 4096);
          @ flush();
        }
      echo "</pre>";
    break;
  case "ping":
      $cmd = "ping -c 5 " . $hostname;
      while (@ ob_end_flush());
      $proc = popen($cmd, 'r');
      echo "<pre>";
      while (!feof($proc))
        {
          echo fread($proc, 4096);
          @ flush();
        }
      echo "</pre>";
   break;
}
```

The above works fine when run in browser directly against the remote server. But of course cURL'ing it from the master does not return live output, it simply returns the finished output once it hits a break point. This is frustrating as, there will be 5-10 of these running on a page simultaneously, and things like traceroutes I would really rather not have to wait until 30 hops time out before the user gets any output from it.

So my overall question here, is.. How can I get cURL to mimic the live PHP output of something like popen and fread above? Can cURL even do that? Can I use another PHP function to get live output from a remote URL until it breaks?

Comment: yup, you want CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, possibly CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, also be wary of php's and your web sever's buffering

Comment: Thank you @hanshenrik. I will look into those curlopt's now and come back with either another question or an answer to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

yes it can, through CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION / CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.. untested, but i think it would go something like this:

```
$ch=curl_init();
$buffer='';//your download buffer goes here.
function progressfunc($ch,$totalDownloadSize,$bytesDownloaded,$totalRequestSize,$bytesUploaded){
    global $buffer;
    echo $buffer;
    $buffer='';
    //echo str_repeat('<span></span>',100);//if you have buffering issues, this is an ugly workaround...
    flush();
};
function writefunc($ch,$data){
    global $buffer;
    static $written=0;
    $buffer.=$data;
    $written+=strlen($data);
    return $written;
};
if(!curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION=>'writefunc',
CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION=>'progressfunc',
CURLOPT_URL=>'slow_download'
))){
    throw new RuntimeException('curl_setopt_array error. errno:'.curl_errno($ch).' error:'.curl_error($ch));
}
curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Many thanks for this insight. I will be implementing this later today and will feedback appropriately